# why the second call of function getCard return the second of the deck?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the second call of function getCard return the second of the deck. Doesn't it always return the first item of the deck because of `deck.shift()`? Why the function will be conducted again like for loop?

And also, when I log out deck at the end, it returns the deck with out the first two items?

```
//
//Blackjack
// by Weilin

let suits=['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades'];
let values=['Ace', 'King','Queen', 'Jack', 'Ten', 'Nine',
'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six','Five','Four', 'Three','Two'];




function createDeck(){
 let deck=[];

for (let suitIdx=0; suitIdx<suits.length;suitIdx++){
  for (let valueIdx=0;valueIdx<values.length; valueIdx++){
  deck.push(values[valueIdx]+ ' of ' + suits[suitIdx]);
  }

}
  return deck;
}

function getNextCard(){
  return deck.shift();
}
let deck= createDeck();



for(let i=0; i<deck.length;i++){
  console.log(deck[i]);
}

let playerCards=[getNextCard(),getNextCard()];

console.log("Welcome to Blackjack!")

console.log("You are dealt:" )
console.log(" "+playerCards[0])
console.log(" "+playerCards[1])
```

Comment: `shift` mutates the existing array.

Answer (score 0):

The `deck.shift()` remove first element from array and return it ([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)) - so if you run it twice, then result will be different (because first call change array). So after call `getNextCard()` twice, two first elements are removed from `desk`. If you don't want to remove first two elements from `desk` but only read them then use instead

```
let first  = deck[0];
let second = deck[1];
```

or to get card at index i

```
let card = deck[i];
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: @WeilinHong don't forget to accept this answer by click on big gray check button on its left side (you can also upvote it by click on upper gray triangle)